# Pro Asp.net MVC 5 Sportstore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a problem with displaying page links from the Sportstore exercise, this part of exercise starts at page 185.

When I have, by default 9 records in the database, it will only show button for 2 pages (each page has 4 items), then I added 5 records more, now it shows 3 pages and remaining 2 items are hidden on Page 4, but there is no button for it.

This is the line from the List View

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory }))
```

and this is the part from the PagingInfo, where it counts supposedly total pages

```
public int TotalPages { get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal) TotalItems/ItemsPerPage); }}
```

Which, if I'm correct, when I have 9 records in the database, it should be Total Items 9 divided by 4 (items per page), which results to 2.something and should ceil to 3 pages, but I am only getting two.

In my product controller in ViewResult I have following part from PagingInfo

```
public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category).OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
            PagingInfo =
                new PagingInfo
                {
                    CurrentPage = page,
                    ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                    TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Products.Count() : repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
                },
                CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Sorry, late edit for my HTML Helper for PageLinks

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
            if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
            {
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");

            }
            tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
            result.Append(tag.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: what is the library that alows you to do that? link to sportstore? could you check the values in TotalPages, TotalItems and Itemsperpage before rendering by using breakpoint?

Comment: I've got the physical book and there's this entire exercise and I did check for the exact numbers and they show correctly, it just does not render as it should.

Comment: Filters u have applied might be returning less number of products, please check totalcount.

Comment: what is PageLinks, could you please respond to my questions about the references to exerce and libraries you use?